# How to configure Squish for Squid caching proxy?

Tags: proxy, squid

Since this question is related to a server, also for Ubuntu, so I am a little bit confused about where to ask this question.

I am currently using Squid 3.1, properly configured and working on a Ubuntu box. But I also have to install Squish for checking per user account usage. For Squish, I can go through [squish source](http://www.ledge.co.za/software/squint/squish/) and [configured squish with squid](http://imyourservertoday.blogspot.in/2009/04/squish-download-manager-for-squid.html) but through these tutorials, I am getting only proxy refused error.

Since there is no documentation for Squish, I am totally helpless to configure Squish with Squid, from a lot of research I just found a blank graphical chart on my localhost (running apache server). I can't upload the snapshot since I don't have more than 10 reputations. Either I missed a few parts of Squish or there is something else, please have a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

This is [link](http://www.ledge.co.za/software/squint/squish/FAQ) to squish FAQ. If you have not already seen it. It contains documentation about configuring squish with squid.

Comment: I will go though this FAQ, but it is not working.

Comment: if its private related use superuser.com